# why my "eval" function doesn't work ,i think it can be print 'b',but not

Tags: python, eval, exec

```
a='''b="ddd"'''
eval(repr(a))
print str(a)
print b
```

Please try to use the code, rather than text, because my English is not very good, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
eval(compile(a,'<string>','exec'))
```

instead of:

```
eval(repr(a))
```

Transcript:

```
>>> a='''b="ddd"'''
>>> eval(compile(a,'<string>','exec'))
>>> print str(a)
b="ddd"
>>> print b
ddd
```

The problem is that you're actually executing the statement `'b="ddd"'` which is not an assignment to `b` but an evaluation of the string.

The `eval()` built-in, when given a string, evaluates it as an expression (not a statement) and returns the result. You can get `eval()` to run non-expression code by giving it a code object, which we create with `compile()` above. In that case it runs the code and returns `None`.

You can see a similar effect if you just enter:

```
>>> 'c=7'
'c=7'
>>> c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
>>> c=7
>>> c
7
>>> '7=d'
'7=d'
>>> 7=d
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Clearly `7=d` is not valid Python, yet `'7=d'` is, for the reason explained above.

Descriptions of the `expr()`, `repr()` and `compile()` built-ins, adequate enough to work this out, were found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html). No built-ins were harmed during the making of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

[eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) is used to evaluate (get the result of) an expression. What you want is dynamic execution of Python code, which is done with [exec](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec):

```
>>> a='''b="ddd"'''
>>> exec(a)
>>> print b
ddd
```

Also note that you should not call repr() before passing the string to either function. You already have a string, calling repr() creates a string representation of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Reconsider whether you really need to use `eval()`.  For example, you can use [`globals()`](http://diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html) like this:

```
>>> globals()['b'] = 'ddd'
>>> print b
ddd
```

But perhaps what you should probably be using is just a **[dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)**:

```
>>> my_namespace = dict()
>>> my_namespace['b'] = 'ddd'
>>> my_namespace
{'b': 'ddd'}
>>> print my_namespace['b']
ddd
```